# Валидация вводимых полей на стороне клиента

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Есть пустое приложение asp.net. Необходимо сделать валидацию на стороне клиента так что бы пользователь просто не мог ввести в поля того чего не нужно. Видел вариант маскирования:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textBox1" Width="70" onkeypress="MaskCheck('d,d')" />
```

В таком виде в поле можно ввести только 1 цифру до запятой и 1 после запятой. Как сделать в таком же роде, но например, если я хочу чтобы вводились только русские символы, в любом количестве, пробелы, backspace и тому подобное.

Как реализовать валидацию на стороне клиента?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы только начинаете делать проект, то рекомендую осваивать не старый ASP.NET, он уже много лет как устарел, а новый ASP.NET Core 2.0 , это более перспективная и современная технология.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72718/discussion-on-question-by-------).

Answer (score 0):

1. Подробно о валидации в asp.net  можно посмотреть здесь 
   https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/19.4.php

Чтобы проверить на наличие только русских букв, то можно написать регулярное выражение в объявлении свойства.

2. Если проще, то можно поймать событие JS input и сделать проверку. Если правильно, то кнопку отправить сделать активной

   ```
   var tb1 = document.getElementById('textBox1');
   tb1.addEventListener("input", function () {
      функцию проверки можно найти готовую на JS
   }
   ```

Comment: Monah2, попробовал ваш способ, вот код `<script type="text/javascript">
    var tb1 = document.getElementById('textBox1');
    tb1.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
        var x = event.charCode;
        if (x > 122)
        {
            alert("Некорректный ввод");
        }
    })
</script>` На строчке `tb1.addEventListener("input", function (event) {` вываливается ошибка, скриншот в вопросе.

Comment: Обычно эта ошибка возникает только в старых браузерах (IE до 9 версии например) Попробуйте другой браузер.

Comment: Попробовал в хроме, там вообще js не отрабатывает.